# NIO non-blocking socketChannel. Data was not received on the other side

Tags: java, android, nio

I have a very strange behaviour during writing to a NIO socket.
In my mobile client I'm using a NIO socketChannel which is configured as follows:

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.socket().connect(address, 10000); 
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
```

then periodically (every 60 seconds) I write some data to this socketChannel (the code here is a little bit simplified):

```
ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

readBuffer.clear();

int numRead = -1;
numRead = socketChannel.read(readBuffer);
Log.write("Read " + numRead + " bytes" );


if(numRead > 0)
{
    processServerResponse(readBuffer);
}
else if(numRead < 0)
{
    // ... re-connect etc.
}

// ...
byte[] msg = getNextMessage();

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(msg);
int numOfBytes = 0;
while(buffer.hasRemaining())
{
    numOfBytes += socketChannel.write(buffer);
}

Log.write("Written " + numOfBytes + " bytes of " + msg.length );
```

And it works. But... Sometimes (very infrequently, may 1 or 2 times per day) my server don't receive data. My client log looks like:

```
Written 10 bytes of 10 
Written 20 bytes of 20 
Written 30 bytes of 30 
Written 40 bytes of 40 
Written 50 bytes of 50
```

and so on. But on the server side it looks like:

```
Received 10 bytes of 10 
Received 50 bytes of 50
```

20, 30 and 40 bytes data records were not received, despite of fact that on the client side it looks like all data was sent without any exceptions! (In reality the server log is a little bit better than this simplified version. So I can see which data was sent (my sent records contain timestamps etc))

Such gaps can be small (2-3 minutes) which is not very bad, but sometimes they can be very big (1-2 hours = 60-120 cycles) and it is really a problem for my customers.

I really have no idea what can be wrong. The data seems to be sent by client, but it never arrives on the server side. I've checked it also with a proxy.

I would be very grateful for any ideas and tips.

P.S. Maybe it plays some role: the client code runs on an Android mobile device which is moving (it is in a car). The internet connection is established through GPRS.

Comment: Looping like that is very poor technique in non-blocking mode. If the write returns zero, you should be selecting on OP_WRITE rather than burning the CPU. What does the receive code look like?

Comment: Thank you for your comment EJP. I don't know how the receive code looks like. The server is not mine and is a "closed source software". But I think it can't be a server problem, because I've tested it with a proxy. So the server architecture should be irrelevant for my problem. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Since it seems you really are losing data - does your server log connects and disconnects?  What does it look like on the server when the mobile goes out of range for a while and then comes back in range.  Based on your server logs, are you absolutely certain that when there is a gap that you are still reading from the same TCP connection?

Comment: Can you post more of the sending code? How does the buffer get filled? When does it get flipped and compacted?

Comment: Thanks, EJP and Guido.
@EJP I've posted some lines of code more. Is it necessary to flip and compact the buffer? In my code the new buffer is created every cycle. May be it is not very good technique but it should work.

Comment: @GuidoSimone: No, I can not be sure that it is the same connection. Connection can be lost,  but it will be automatically re-established.

Comment: A buffer created by wrap() is already flipped. I suggest you have over-simplified the code for posting here, and lost the problem in the process. Maybe for example you are ignoring an exception somewhere, e.g. during reconnection, so you think you've written but you haven't?

Comment: May be, but it is really not much more code there :( 
And I didn't have any ignored exceptions during  reconnection. Because I can see reconnection attempts in my log. But it looks like I have absolutely no connection or writing problems. I'm writing data without any problems but the server didn't receive it. It is really strange and frustrating...

Comment: Remember that even if socketChannel.write returns without an error - all that means is those bytes are sitting in a buffer somewhere getting ready for transmission.  They have not been transmitted yet.  If TCP on the client kills the connection because it's not receiving any ACKS from the server, then those bytes have not been transmitted and when the connection is destroyed those bytes are lost.  In which case you have to handle this situation at the application level.  To determine if this is the case you must check the server log and see if a reconnect happens about the time you lost data.

Comment: @GuidoSimone That doesn't explain the hole in the data. Subsequent data got through, according to the OP. Holes in the data are impossible in TCP.